# What does this strikethrough on the arrow mean? is it not bi-directional?

Tags: schematics, circuits

I'm trying to find out if the main DSP core can communicate with an external DSP via I2S . I'm not sure what that strike-through means.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that it is a bus with multiple signals.

It can't be used to determine anything specific about the I2S  bus, such as data direction or clock direction, but generally I2S devices are quite versatile that they can receive clocks from another device or send clocks to another device.

Comment: @whoknowsmerida sometimes there will also be a small number above the strike through to indicate how many signals are in the bus.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Thanks Tom